# System.XML not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Issue:
     When I enter "using System.XML;" to my project the following error appears:
"The type or namespace name 'XML' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Environment:
     Visual Studio 2010
     System.XML and System.Xml.Linq are in References.
     The version of the System.XML is 4.0.0
     The Target Framework is ".Net Framework 4"

I removed System.XML and readded it from "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.XML\2.0.0.0_b77a5c561934e089\System.XML.dll"
I changed the Target Framework from ".Net Framework 4" to ".Net Framework 3", saved it, reloaded the project, switched it back and reloaded the project.

I'm looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx. At the bottom of the page it has 
Reference
    System.Xml.Path
    System.Xml.Xsl
    System.Xml.Schema
    System.Xml.Linq
I am unable to find those in C:\Windows\assembly

Is there another assembly Visual Studio is looking for, besides System.XML.dll to use "using System.XML?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace is `System.Xml`. not `System.XML`.